# Generate HTML and PDF

Tags: html, xml, pdf, web, xslt

I'm thinking of the way I'd generate a university newspaper both in PDF and HTML (a website) where every news would contain picture(s) and wonder if there any tools to approach this problem declaratively so that unexperienced users would prepare structured data (text + pictures) and get PDF and website on output on their own with no programmers' intervention. I suspect it can be some sort of XSL-FO, XML editing/processing software.

P. S. A free tool(s) would be a best solution.

Thank you.

Comment: What language is your site programmed in?

Comment: @Paddy: There's no site so far, an approach I'm looking for would solve the problem of generating it. Actually it is expected to contain only news within the last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, a very good approach would be to use [DocBook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook)
to write your articles, than let the tools generate HTML and PDFs you need - with just some tuning of the look and feel output from your side.

For DocBook there are many available tools, but a very good one that is free for open source and academics is [XMLMind](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/)

If your articles are more technical oriented, than **DocBook** is the quasi-standard (even many publishing houses like O'Reilly use it)

Of course, in the "pure" academics domain, **LaTex** is quite the standard (and allows to have output in allot of formats), but requires quite allot to learn it, and there are no true [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) tools to write the articles. If you intend to send the articles to some research papers too, than they are very glad to accept your LaTex input.

Comment: @A. Ionescu: Just a newspaper which describes the past and forthcoming events.

Comment: @Yasir: In this case you may very well use a full blown word processor like OpenOffice Write, and generate from there the desired HTML and PDFs - since it is the most comfortable type of tool when writing.

Answer (score 1):

we (swansea University) used a content management system to achive this - DotNetNuke in our instance.

We wanted multipage newletter where a summary on the newletter and click more for the fuller article.  The content management system allowed normal users to use the software to construct the newletter, they simple created a new child site every month.

We had the newletter emailed out, we we simply grabbed the html from the main page and sent to a distribution list.

Something worth considering - cost = £0

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way of doing it would be to generate all your content in XML, then use either a commercial XSL-FO processor for PDF, or apache FOP to generate the PDF, and whatever your XSL processor is to generate the html.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to Simon Thompson's answer:

You can use [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal) and [its print module](http://drupal.org/project/print).